# Flex: Recording audio directly form soundcard

Tags: apache-flex, audio, recording, soundcard

I am new to flex but my first app is a little bit more pro than you would expect form a rookie. I would like to record sound that is currently played on the local computer (i.e. form winamp or youtube). I saw some codes that use the microphone, but this is undesired. The client machine may not have a microphone hardware or may play the sound on headphones. I think this must be possible but may be not a common task so that's why I can't find the solution? Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the user of your app has to select their "input device" and allow access for the Flash web baesd app to access that input device.  But, once they do the choosing, you should be able to access that Audio feed using the same microphone APIs.

bring up the Flash Player context menu and select settings.  then click the microphone tab.  You should see a list of all possibly options.  at this moment, one option I have is "Stereo Mix" which I'm pretty sure will send out all the info from the computer.

Comment: Yes I have figured this one, but I am wondering is there a possibility to do this automatically so the user doesn't have to pick the recording device by himself. So the audio mixer would be the default device and if not present (or muted) we change to microphone. Unfortunately the results returned by Microphone.names seem to be dependent on the OS, system's language or the hardware itself.... Does any one have any idea?

Comment: @srd.pl The user must select the input device and allow the app access to use them.  This is due to the security sandbox limitations of the Flash Player in the browser.  There is no amount of ACtionScript code you can write to get around this.